# Material Design Guidelines (xml examples)

Tags: android, material-design

Are there any readily available material design (as per google's material design guidelines) style templates (styles.xml) which i can use as base and quickly build my ui on top of that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Google docs](http://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html) just choose one of the following themes for your application:

> @android:style/Theme.Material (dark version)
>
> @android:style/Theme.Material.Light (light version)
>
> @android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar

Then apply it in your AndroidManifest.xml like this:

```
<application
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material"
        ... >
```

Of course you can [extend your own theme](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) from one of the above.